# Charting library that offers Linked line chart with dots

Tags: php, apache-flex, charts, data-visualization, degrafa

I'm trying to plot data from several entities over time.

- Each entity will have its own line, so there will be several lines.
- Each line will be connected, but it's important that dots are drawn to represent data.

I'm aware of the linked bar chart, but at initial inspection, I can't seem to find one that offers me the ability to draw the dots. Anyone knows which library has this? I'm open to PHP, Flex, degrafa, whatever else that gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

ChartDirector will do it, but not for free. http://www.advsofteng.com/

I'm sure there are others, but this is the one I use.

Examples here: http://www.advsofteng.com/gallery_line.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com). It can easily do this and there's a free, fully functional version.